# Ubuntu 14.04 - need help on umount

Tags: ubuntu, umount

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.  I am trying to create a bootable memory card for my tinkerboard.  When i do

`lsblk`

I get the following output:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 458.1G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   7.7G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1  14.9G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1    64M  0 part /media/mycomp/7458-EBF2
└─sdb2   8:18   1  14.8G  0 part /media/mycomp/7496-D5D4
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

In this sdb is what I have to unmount.  I issued the following command:

```
sudo umount /sdb
sudo umount /sdb/sdb*
sudo umount /sdb/sdb1
sudo umount /sdb/sdb2
```

None of them works.  How can I unmount the memory card so that I can write img file into the memory card.

`mount` command shows these options though: among various options:-

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/mycomp/7458-EBF2 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb2 on /media/mycomp/7496-D5D4 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)
```

However, when I try

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
sudo umount /dev/sdb2
sudo umount /dev/sdb*
```

I get the similar error

```
/dev/sdb1 not mounted
```

Comment: An example error message `umount: /sdb: not found` : common for all the options

Comment: How about `/dev/sdb1`? :) What is the output of `mount` in the first place?

Comment: i did that too...getting similar error...have updated my question

Comment: Try `sudo umount /media/mycomp/7458-EBF2`